# How to Enable PHP 7.0 Zip module on Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, php-7

Using the command line, I have installed PHP 7.0 on the Amazon Linux AMI.
However, I am unable to install the PHP Zip Module using the command

```
sudo yum install php7.0-zip
```

I get the response

```
No package php7.0.zip available.
```

I am excited to start using PHP7 on all my PHP websites, but am a little confused why I am unable to install this particular module. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welp, 
After trying several variations of the same command...

```
sudo yum install php7.0-zip

sudo yum install php7-zip
```

**THIS ONE WORKS**

```
sudo yum install php70-zip
```